# SOAP-UI - How to retrieve the second body part in a multipart response and asserting the same

Tags: response, soapui, multipart, wildcard, assertion

We have a RESTful webservice that gives back a Multiparty response.
The first body part is an xml and the second is an xhtml.
I am able to retrieve the first bodypart and assert.
However, I am unable to retreive the second body part so that I can do the XPath assertion on the same.
The second body part was coming as an attachment. Using grrovy script, I am able to access is attachment and do a string comparison with the expected xhtml.
To add to the misery, my requirement is to ignore few attributes present in specific tags as the value will be dynamic for every request and has to ignored while performing assertion. This was easier to achieve in XPath assertion by making use of "Allow wildcards" option.

My questions are:
1. Is there a way to assert the second body part using XPath assertion.
2. If no, how can the assertion be peformed using groovy script by ignoring few attributes present in the actual xhtml/xml.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: This image is difficult to see. An explanation would help make this answer a better one.